# API Platform: Denormalization serialization for nested data with custom identifier (NOT the entity primary key)

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

How to use a custom identifier (not the primary key) on denormalization for nested data?

I am already using Groups for nested data, in order to normalize/denormalize my resource.

I have the below JSON which is used to create an:

- invoice

  - invoiceLine

    - item

```
{
    "total": "1060.000",
    "paid": "1100.000",
    "status": true,
    "invoiceLine": [
        {
            "price": "460.000",
            "quantity": 1,
            "item": {
                "clientItemId": 9,
                "name": "laptop",
                "price": "13000",
                "category": "/categories/2"
            }
        },
        {
            "price": "600.000",
            "quantity": 2,
            "item": {
                "clientItemId": 10,
                "name": "screen",
                "price": "300.000",
                "category": "/categories/2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I make sure that items are not always created (duplicated), using the `clientItemId` instead of the entity `id`?

> Note: that I can not use `clientItemId` as my primary key since I have different clients, and 2 clients might have the same value for `clientItemId` (think of it as a unique ref. code given by the client), that is why I have my own generated value `id`.

### Entity Classes

#### api/src/Entity/InvoiceLine.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\InvoiceLineRepository")
 */
class InvoiceLine
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     * @Groups({"order"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=15, scale=2)
     *
     * @Groups({"order"})
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     * @Groups({"order"})
     */
    private $quantity;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(
     *     targetEntity="App\Entity\Invoice",
     *     inversedBy="InvoiceLines"
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $invoice;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(
     *     targetEntity="App\Entity\Item",
     *     cascade={"persist"}
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     *
     * @Groups({"order"})
     */
    private $item;
...
```

#### api/src/Entity/Item.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiSubresource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ItemRepository")
 */
class Item
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     * @Groups({"order"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     *
     * @Groups({"order"})
     */
    private $clientItemId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @Groups({"order"})
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=15, scale=3)
     *
     * @Groups({"order"})
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\ItemCategory", inversedBy="Items")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     *
     * @Groups({"order"})
     */
    private $ItemCategory;
...
```

Comment: Do you have an entity `Item` with the properties: `clientItemId`, `name`, `price`, `category`? Does it have a field `invoiceLine` as `ManyToOne` relation to `InvoiceLine`?

Comment: @cezar Added InvoiceLine and Item entities content, btw Item is linked from InvoiceLine entity only.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. No, you cannot use a non-unique id to identify an entity. Yes, you can include the primary key to identify the `item`.

Comment: How about a custom denormalizer?

Comment: You want to check if there is already an item with the same clientItemId before inserting to DB ?

Comment: The main concern is that if there is already a record with the same clientItemId, update this row instead of adding a new record.
Currently, every time a request is sent a new record (an entity ID), which is another record for the same clientItemId.

Comment: @GeoSalameh have you managed to solve this issue? I'm currently facing the same problem where the API Platform is trying to Insert a new Entity instead of updating an existing one.